# How to convert String into char in dart

Tags: java

I want to convert string into a character. I am trying to send Gender M or F to the API but the api only supports char data type. and it is giving error when we try to pass like this.

`String gender = "M";`

Is there any way to convert the string into the character ??

Comment: are you aware of String's charAt method?

Comment: Are you asking about Java or Dart?

Comment: I am asking about the dart but the API has been written in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart, you can convert a string to list of chars by using the [split](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.1/dart-core/String/split.html) method.

```
var str = "M";
str.split(""); // ['M']
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [charAt](https://pub.dev/documentation/quartet/latest/quartet/charAt.html) method:

```
var str = "M";
str.charAt(0); // 'M'
```

Comment: non of the above code is working.

Comment: @swapnilmane - You can see that it works in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?). What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Yes sir. it is working now.